# Get sum of integers each hour on MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a tabe in MySQL with columns `id` (INT), `count` (INT) and `event_timestamp` (LONG). I'm trying to make a query that will return the sum of all counts for each hour, but I'm not sure what path to take. I have managed to get the hourly values for each one but that's about it

`SELECT DISTINCT 
  FLOOR(
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
      DATE_ADD(
        DATE_FORMAT(
          from_unixtime(
            es.event_timestamp/1000
          ),
          "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"
        ), 
        INTERVAL 0 MINUTE
      )
    )
  *1000
  )
 as t FROM metrics.event_summary es;`

I know it's an odd way to parse the SQL but the function for the timestamps I got was overly complicated.

What's the best most efficient way to finish this off?

Comment: Your life would be so much easier if you use a proper datetime/timestamp column to store `event_timestamp`

Comment: @Mike Brant This is how the table was built and theres 550 million records here. I have to work with it like this. :(

Comment: if you include sample data, it will be great?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Unix time stamp, just divide by 60*60 or 60*60*1000 (depending on whether it is in seconds or milliseconds).

```
select floor(es.event_timestamp/(1000*60*60)) as hour_timestamp,
       sum(`count`) as cnt
from metrics.event_summary es
group by floor(es.event_timestamp/(1000*60*60))
order by hour_timestamp;
```

Comment: This seems to work and is a lot simpler than what I already had! Testing it!